# IPython Notebook - early exit from cell

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to programmatically exit a cell early in IPython Notebook. `exit(0)`, however, kills the kernel.

Whats the proper way to do this? I'd prefer not to split the cell or manually halt execution.

Comment: Can you explain why? If you're determined to only run half the code in a cell and then stop, I guess you could raise an exception, but I'm not sure what purpose that would serve.

Comment: @andi: that's incorrect. my question asks about halting execution of a single cell, not exiting the entire notebook!

Comment: I am sorry, I was confused by your title exit from cell. Thought you meant notebook.

Comment: @Marius: it's a development strategy. i still like to run large blocks of code in one go inside a single cell, but often want to query variable state without running the whole thing. i'm relatively new to IPN and previously used exit(0) to do this when developing via command line scripts.

Comment: @andi: can you unflag the duplicate?

Comment: Actually I did. No Idea why it didn't. I think a Moderator will undo it after seeing the comments. Again, sorry about that.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214799/can-i-stop-execution-of-current-module-in-ipython-without-leaving-ipython

Comment: @watsonic: The closest thing I can think of to your desired workflow would be to open up an Ipython console that uses the same kernel as the notebook with `ipython qtconsole --existing`, and copy-paste the lines you actually want to run from the notebook into the console when you want to quickly check things.

Comment: @Marius: thanks but thats a bit more involved than what i want to do (copy pasting etc). i see IPN as nice because its self contained.

Comment: @andi i took inspiration from one [answer on that page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18939511/695804) (which actually fails since its a pre-runtime syntax error) to produce an imperfect solution below. thanks!

Comment: Great that it worked out. Nice effort and cool solution ;)

Comment: One way to do this is by putting your code into a function. You then use a `return None` to exit early - without throwing an error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm reposting my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893461/problems-exiting-from-python-using-ipython-spyder/48000399#48000399) because the solution should apply to your question as well. It will...

- not kill the kernel on exit
- not display a full traceback (no traceback for use in IPython shell)
- not force you to entrench code with try/excepts
- work with or without IPython, without changes in code

Just import 'exit' from the code beneath into your jupyter notebook (IPython notebook) and calling 'exit()' should work. It will exit and letting you know that...

```
 An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

 IpyExit
```

---

```
"""
# ipython_exit.py
Allows exit() to work if script is invoked with IPython without
raising NameError Exception. Keeps kernel alive.

Use: import variable 'exit' in target script with
     'from ipython_exit import exit'    
"""

import sys
from io import StringIO
from IPython import get_ipython


class IpyExit(SystemExit):
    """Exit Exception for IPython.

    Exception temporarily redirects stderr to buffer.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # print("exiting")  # optionally print some message to stdout, too
        # ... or do other stuff before exit
        sys.stderr = StringIO()

    def __del__(self):
        sys.stderr.close()
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__  # restore from backup


def ipy_exit():
    raise IpyExit


if get_ipython():    # ...run with IPython
    exit = ipy_exit  # rebind to custom exit
else:
    exit = exit      # just make exit importable
```

Comment: How could the early exit from the cell be used in a Kaggle kernel Notebook ?

Comment: @shauryaairi Sorry, I haven't used Kaggle yet so I don't know.

Comment: What isn't there a builtin way to do this?

Comment: How do I hide `An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.`?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira As far as I remember, you don't, which is why the answer mentions you'll get this message. The answer is bit old already, maybe there's a way today I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 64):

Slightly more "proper" options:

This will get you out of all but the worst try/except blocks.

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt
```

A little cleaner version of yours:

```
assert(False)
```

or simply:

```
raise
```

if you want to save a couple keystrokes.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's messy, you get a traceback. It would be nice to find a solution that ends execution quietly.

Answer (score 64):

To stop current and subsequent cells quietly:

```
class StopExecution(Exception):
    def _render_traceback_(self):
        return []

raise StopExecution
```

Comment: very clean, thanks! Now I can do ``def exit(): raise StopExecution``.

Comment: As per https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/4f6e132d2fc56feabd9d87cac98906d3e5806d6a/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L1994 `_render_traceback_` is meant to return list of strings. So the method should probably do `return []` instead of `pass`. With `pass` I was hitting exceptions when using nbconvert.

Answer (score 4):

Not saying this is a good idea, but you can wrap the start of the cell in a single iteration for loop, then call 'break' to stop further execution.

```python
for _ in range(1):
    # do some stuff
    if some_condition:
        break
```

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution. And, more, if we re-use the code in a function (using jupyter to tests/prototype), we just have to change the "break(s)" in return

Answer (score 0):

This is far from "proper" but one way to exit early is to create a runtime error. So instead of returning early from a script cleanly with `exit(0)` one can return uncleanly with something like

```
print(variable_to_query)
() + 1
```

which will run the code up until this point (completing the print statement) and then fail.

Comment: what is the difference than any other error like inserting some non existing variable or typing 0/0?

Comment: No difference. Arbitrary