# How to gracefully exit from ipython script on jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython, exit

I am new at coding. I am working on jupyter notebook using anaconda environment. I have this sample code where I am using sys.exit() command. When it gets executed it exits script with several error messages. Here is my sample code.

```
import sys

name = 'joh'
if name == 'john':
    print('Name matches')
else:
    print('Incorrect name')
    sys.exit(0)

... some more code
```

Upon execution, it returns

```
Incorrect name
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0


C:\Users\ankur.kulshrestha\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

How can I gracefully exit the script without receiving all these error messages (apart from the first line which I have actually put in the code.)

Comment: You should not be exiting at all from the Jupyter Notebook. That's the reason for the message.

Comment: But I want to exit script execution. Means if name doesn't match I don't want to execute rest of the following code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython Notebook - early exit from cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005221/ipython-notebook-early-exit-from-cell)

Comment: Then put that code in a different cell and don't execute it. Or put it in a function and don't call the function.