# Exit from a Jupyter notebook within another

Tags: jupyter-notebook, return, ipython, call, exit

I am performing different types of analyses over some data.
I keep the preprocessing, main iteration, and plotting in one ‘main.ipynb’.

From one cells that loops over chunks of the data I call another notebook using %run ‘analysis.ipynb’. This allows me to keep the logic separated and well documented.

Usually all cells of ‘analysis.ipynb’ are executed. But sometimes the data does not qualify for all the cells in ‘analysis.ipynb’ so I do a check, and I want to return to the main nb.

So far I found this [IPython Notebook - early exit from cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005221/ipython-notebook-early-exit-from-cell)

But it works by raising an exception, which blocks the loop in ‘main.ipynb’.

How can I exit the execution of ‘analysis.ipynb’ without blocking the execution of’main.ipynb’?